# Array data created in one screen doesn't get displayed in other screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bootstrap-4

In a React project, I've two screens in which one screen array is created and passed as props to other screen. The second screen doesn't display the array data. Please refer to the code below

Below is the JSON data from first screen

```
const newCompData = [
    {
      id: 1,
      comp: "McDonalds",
      feedback: "Best Food Chain",
      name: "Mike John",
      store: "Burger Store"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      comp: "KFC",
      feedback: "Best Chicken Products",
      store: "Chicken Food",
      name: "Steve Williams"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      comp: "Dominos",
      feedback: "Best Pizza Store",
      store: "Pizza Store",
      name: "Mark Rays",
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      comp: "Star Bucks",
      feedback: "Best Coffee Store",
      store: "Coffee Store",
      name: "Patrick Right",
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      comp: "Burger King",
      feedback: "Best Burgers",
      store: "Burger Store",
      name: "Williams Wills"
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      comp: "Lays",
      feedback: "Best Chips Factory",
      store: "Chips Store",
      name: "Sam Andrews",
    }
  ];
```

This is how I map the above array of object data

```
const [dataAll, setDataAll] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const newData = newCompData?.map((data) => {
      return [{ id: data.id }, data.comp, data.store, data.name, data.feedback];
    });

    setDataAll(newData);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Table newData={dataAll} />
    </div>
  );
```

Now the second screen Table.js

```
const Table = ({ newData }) => {

// Checking for newData value and is getting in console  
console.log("PROPS", newData);
  const store_grid_data = {
    data: newData,
    page_info: {
      total_pages: 5,
      current_page: 1
    }
  };

  let GridConfig = {};
  let grid_data = {};

  GridConfig = TableConfig;
  grid_data = store_grid_data;

  const [gridConfigData, setGridConfigData] = useState(GridConfig);
  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState(grid_data);

  return (
    <>
      <Grid GridConfig={gridConfigData} GridData={gridData} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Array data isn't getting displayed in the above mentioned second screen. The data which I've created is similar as JSON data from API. What could be the best solution to tackle this issue. Any suggestions highly appreciated

Following is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-boyd-2e16j6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please change Table.js file render function, here we don't need to set gridValue using useState(), you can pass that value directly in props

```
import TableConfig from "./TableConfig";
import { useState } from "react";
import Grid from "./Grid";

const Table = ({ newData }) => {
  console.log("PROPS", newData);
  const store_grid_data = {
    data: newData,
    page_info: {
      total_pages: 5,
      current_page: 1
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Grid GridConfig={TableConfig} GridData={store_grid_data} />
    </>
  );
};

export default Table;
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.... if you don't mind can you update it sandbox please... since the data isn't getting mapped properly

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-snow-x5qh8q?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thanks for quick response... but, corresponding data isn't matched as expected... like under Name 'name' data should be populated, similarly for feedback 'feedback' data

Comment: See if its possible... its intense request

Comment: please check now, i have changed the code in sandbox, if it's helpful to you, then please give me vote and useful answer. THANKS.!

Comment: Appreciate your hard work.... Thanks... but, we want data in array format only... the one that was returned in useeffect in my sandbox... useeffect is removed and table structure is altered here

Comment: Its ok... really thanks for the efforts you have put... I will raise another question for it